# Kernel panic at boot with BusyBox and init error messages

Tags: boot-failure, init, kernel, busybox

How do I reboot my computer?

A friend of mine started my computer over from scratch, then installed Ubuntu on my computer.

But, when my computer ran out of power and I charged it, the computer turned on with this message:

```
BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)
Enter help for a list of built in commands.
```

After this, I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> a couple of times, and then typed `exit`, then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few more times.

I then saw this message:

```
/init: line 271: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
[     138.437851] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

What should I do? I can't afford to buy another computer right now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide us with some more information regarding your setup? I noticed you mentioned charging your system, so I take it you are using a laptop.

Comment: Rest assured, you will not have to buy another computer. This sounds like it's strictly a software problem.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Okay. Well, is there anything I can do? Since I have Ubuntu on my computer, what would be the best way to make it work?